# When are Magento rule-based product relations worked out?

Tags: magento

Magento's rule-based product relations (up-sell, cross-sell etc) are stored in a database table, and I assume they are updated once in a while. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation about when that happens or what triggers it. Is it:

- Cached, like a block, and expires after a certain time?
- Generated whenever you save a product?
- Generated by CRON?

I'd really appreciate it is someone could fill in the blanks for me. I'm using the Enterprise edition, if that helps or makes any difference.

Comment: if you are using Enterprise then you should ask it from Enterprise support as you are paying for it and they will answer

Comment: If you do end up asking the Enterprise Support folks, please make sure to post the answer back here for the benefit of others. Half the fun of SO is being able to find your answer quickly to a question that has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug around the product link data a bit. The relevant object we're looking at here is `catalog/product_link`, which the `catalog/product` object uses to retrieve linked object data.

While grouped and bundle products seem to write to this in cronjobs, I have not found any cases where this data is written in a cron-job for actual upsell/cross-sell products. I will keep digging a bit, but this seems to imply that the products are calculated at save time.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I've not been able to absolutely verify this, but it matches what I've seen in the last few weeks - as far as I can tell, the related items are only worked out when the product is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the observers on events "catalog_product_save_before" and "catalog_product_save_after" to see in your project when it is fired and what function is called.

In the enterprise edition the observer fired is enterprise_targetrule/observer, function : catalogProductAfterSave ...